# Using HTML5 with eclipse android plugin

Tags: android, eclipse, html, eclipse-plugin

I am completely new to Android so forgive me if this is trivial. I have installed eclipse Android plugin, it has toolbox for implementing the UI. Is there a way I use HTML code here.

Thanks,
Sara.

Comment: If you are completely new to android you will first need to learn the basics. The structure of an android project, how to interact between your main activity and the UI layout resources. Google for tutorials.. I know that I purchased a book and followed along until I got it. Once there a WebView, like I put in my answer below is the specific Android layout you will need to use. Best of luck exposing your HTML to everyone on Android.

Comment: Thanks all. I have started with a book now "Android in action". Since I am good at HTML5 but could see only xml there, I wondered if I should leave all that behind! So I'll explore these and get back to you to accept your answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking to develop HTML 5 Applications?
then you need some other frameworks, which will help you to build android apps using your HTML, CSS, Javascript codes

What I use for this is [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/)

Many more frameworks are available. You can google it.

Answer (score 1):

To add a WebView to your Application, simply include the  element in your activity layout. For example, here's a layout file in which the WebView fills the screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>


String summary = "<html><body>Awesome Content Here</body></html>";
 webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try phonegap api

Answer (score 0):

To include the HTML code in Android application. you can follow the above example and you can put your all HTML code in **res** folder and make a new folder **www** and put following line in your activity class

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_assest/www/index.html");
```